# Text field in iOS view controller customising

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I want to display a large amount of text in a view controller.
The text will have different bulletpoints and different words will have different colours.
How would you go about doing this?
Is there anyway to set this up and then import to the view controller? 
Example of the editing I need to achieve is below- how could I copy this or code for this in swift

First line
Piperacillin-tazobactam (RED)  (Tazocin®) 4.5g IV TDS (8 hourly)

Consider if severe infection:
Add: Stat dose of Gentamicin(GREEN) 5mg/kg (see Antibiotic dosing & monitoring)

Consider oral switch after 48 hours to Co-amoxiclav (RED)

Non-severe penicillin allergy
Cefuroxime(amber)  1.5g IV TDS (8 hourly)
+ Metronidazole(GREEN) 500mg IV TDS (8 hourly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end i am using sketch to create the text then exporting out as a png and importing to the veiwcontroller uiimageview